# Python Matrix equation solving method

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

What method should i use?

a,b are vectors, or arrays n dimensionals, and X is (nxn) dimensional.  Im using numpy for this.

I have a

X^T X a=X^T b

matrix vector equation. X,X^T,b is known and the question is a.

I have tried X^T X as X^T@X=z and doing z^-1, then
z^-1@X^T =g and doing np.linalg.solve(g,b). Is there some basic linear algebra i'm doing wrong here?

Is there a specific python code for these types of equations?

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there a specific python code for these types of equations?"*

Yes.  The problem that you are solving is [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) (see also [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares)).

NumPy has the function [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) for solving such problems.  In your case, to compute `a` given `X` and `b`, you would use

```
a, residuals, rank, singvals = np.linalg.lstsq(X, b)
```

`residuals`, `rank` and `singvals` are additional information returned by `lstsq`, as explained in the docstring.